# How to fix "ComputerVisionErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'PermissionDenied'"

Tags: python, io, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

I am getting `ComputerVisionErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'PermissionDenied'` when trying to analyse image by passing an argument, if I am giving input as a variable, there is no error. Please help on giving input as variable.

```py
path = raw_input("enter path: ")

# --snip--

with open(os.path.join(IMAGES_FOLDER, path), "rb") as image_stream:

# --snip--
```

It works fine. But I am trying to use:

```py
path = sys.argv[1]
```

However, I get the error above. I want it to work just fine as it is with taking an input.

Comment: `PermissionDenied` usually means one of two things: the API key is not set correctly, or the endpoint and API key don't match.  Can you share more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Install the Azure Cognitive Services Computer Vision SDK for Python and use the SDK for querying

```
pip install azure-cognitiveservices-vision-computervision
```

**Authentication**

Once you create your Computer Vision resource, you need its endpoint, and one of its account keys to instantiate the client object.

Use these values when you create the instance of the ComputerVisionClient client object.

**Create Client**

Get the endpoint and key from environment variables then create the ComputerVisionClient client object.

```
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision import ComputerVisionClient
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision.models import VisualFeatureTypes
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials

# Get endpoint and key from environment variables
import os
endpoint = os.environ['ACCOUNT_ENDPOINT']
key = os.environ['ACCOUNT_KEY']

# Set credentials
credentials = CognitiveServicesCredentials(key)

# Create client
client = ComputerVisionClient(endpoint, credentials)
```

**Analyze an Image**

You can analyze an image for certain features with analyze_image. Use the visual_features property to set the types of analysis to perform on the image. Common values are VisualFeatureTypes.tags and VisualFeatureTypes.description.

```
url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/12/Broadway_and_Times_Square_by_night.jpg/450px-Broadway_and_Times_Square_by_night.jpg"

image_analysis = client.analyze_image(url,visual_features=[VisualFeatureTypes.tags])

for tag in image_analysis.tags:
    print(tag)
```

Visit [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/tree/master/articles/cognitive-services/Computer-vision/quickstarts-sdk) for reference.

Hope it helps.

Comment: When I run this code, I get the error: "ComputerVisionErrorResponseException: (InvalidRequest) Image URL is not accessible." Why can't the API (or Python?) access this URL, even though I can browse to it?